# Retrieve contact info thru inputmethod IME

Tags: android, contacts, ime, android-input-method

I'm creating my own InputMethod (IME). When the user is typing a message to a contact using my IME, I would like to retrieve the contact's info and its attributes.

Or, rephrase, how to get the info on the Contact on screen?

( Can my app communicate with the messaging app on screen and get the Contact? )

Note: I can write attributes to the contacts. I'm thinking of retrieving those too.

Comment: which contact's info you are talking about ? users's own contact ?

Comment: yeah, anyone on the phone's Contact List that they are texting

Comment: I don't think you can directly communicate with that app about which contact messeging app is working on

Answer (score 0):

> Can my app communicate with the messaging app on screen and get the
>   Contact?

No. From within your IME, you can get info about the field that you are currently editing.

> how to get the info of the Contact on screen?

Using [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html).

> An accessibility service runs in the background and receives callbacks
>   by the system when AccessibilityEvents are fired. Such events denote
>   some state transition in the user interface, for example, the focus
>   has changed, a button has been clicked, etc. **Such a service can
>   optionally request the capability for querying the content of the
>   active window.** Development of an accessibility service requires
>   extending this class and implementing its abstract methods.